# Custom Port for Percona Mongodb Exporter

Tags: mongodb, performance, monitoring, prometheus, percona

How can I monitor multiple mongodb clusters from the same ec2 machine? I want to hit multiple mongo db URIs and scrape their metrics. A solution I'm thinking of is starting mongodb exporter at different ports, one for each mongodb URI (cluster) but I'm not able to figure how to specify custom port for mongodb exporter to start at. I would want to start one instance of Percona mongodb exporter at 9216 port and another at suppose 9000 port.
Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out from here : https://github.com/percona/mongodb_exporter/blob/master/testdata/mongodb_exporter.testFlagHelp.golden

There is a flag option - --web.listen-address=":9216"
Address to listen on for web interface and
telemetry.